# How to use HTML image tag in PHP string?

Tags: php, html, string, image

I want to integrate an image in this php string. What am I doing wrong?

```
$answer .= '<p> '.<img src=\"/assets/img/back.png\" alt=\"back" />.' '.PMF_String::substr($outstr, 0, -2).'  </p>';
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The syntax highlighting alone answers this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some problems with ' and " .
Here is the right way:

```
$answer .= '<p> <img src="/assets/img/back.png" alt="back" />' . PMF_String::substr($outstr, 0, -2) . '  </p>';
```

Comment: Escaping the quotes is unnessecary in this example.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @GeraldSchneider. I made the changes

Answer (score 2):

no need for escaping the " just try this :

```
$answer .= '<p><img src="assets/img/back.png" alt="back" /> '.PMF_String::substr($outstr, 0, -2).'  </p>';
```

**PS :** you only need to escape the " if the string is surrended by them example :

```
$foo = "<input id=\"myid\" value=\"myvalue\" />";
```

if not and your string is surended by '

```
$foo = '<input id="myid" value="myvalue" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

@Maxi said, it is just wrong in terms of quotes.

But please be aware, that `"` and `'` ar not designed to build up strings with nested quotes.
They are often used for that, but there is another difference to them, as described here:
http://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-double-quotes-vs-single-quotes/

The `""`-enclosed string will be evaluated, while the `''`-enclosed string wont. So there is a *tiny* performance difference. Knowing this difference you should "rather" escape single and/or double codes, than just using both in a nested way.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$answer .= '<p> <img src=\"/assets/img/back.png\" alt=\"back\" /> '.PMF_String::substr($outstr, 0, -2).'  </p>';
```

I can't take you a complete explication of the code because my bad english. Sorry :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$answer .= '<p> '.<img src="/assets/img/back.png" alt="back" />.
'.PMF_String::substr($outstr, 0, -2).'  </p>'
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to escape string. Use alternative quote:

```
$answer .= '<p><img src="/assets/img/back.png" alt="back" />'.PMF_String::substr($outstr, 0, -2).'</p>';
```

Comment: And this exactly what he shouldn't do, cause of the reason outlined in my post.

Comment: This is a fix for the problem, but if you take a look at @dognose 's answer, `""` are not a good idea for just literal string such as :
`<p><img src='/assets/img/back.png' alt='back' />`
and `</p>`

Comment: @Sourav: If you would have choosen `'` as the outer quote and `"` for the attributes, then it would have been perfectly fine :)

Comment: this way is simpler than using same quote and also useful for the beginner who feels uncomfortable for escape string. for performance single quote is better then double quote.

Comment: @dognose, yes, thats true.

Comment: un-downvoted for the update :)